# Is one way better than the other when creating a toLowerCase function?

Tags: javascript

Angular creates a wrapper function for the String.toLowerCase i assume so it can be called as an angular method. ie. angular.lowercase(string). Looking at their code - wanted to get feedback on their approach and if it better than another pattern/approach that I seen and used.

angular way

```
var lowercase = function(string) {
  return isString(string) ? string.toLowerCase : string;
};

lowercase("MYSTRING"); // mystring
```

The other way (which I assumed would be in their code is)

```
var lowercase = Function.prototype.call.bind(''.toLowerCase);

lowercase("MYSTRING"); // mystring

// notes
// ''.toLowerCase as in String.prototype.toLowerCase
// isString() in 1st function another function in angular
```

Is it just that there's *more than one way to cook an egg..* or is their any obvious advantages to the first approach?

Comment: Why not use: javascripts toLowerCase() method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp

Comment: I'd say the "angular way" is more readable than the "other way"

Comment: For consistency, if you're using AngularJS, you should probably follow their recommended guidelines (i.e. do it the "angular way").

Comment: Cheers thanks for all responses - @war10ck it is not so much about doing it the angular way so much - bc you are using angular.lowercase in angular app anyway. I just was wondering for my own coding practices, really.

Comment: Tom - thx kinda agree @Geohut - tough to explain in a sentence. But sometimes have accessed as a function - to be able to use within libraries and api's, etc

Comment: edit from last comment- But sometimes you need it as a direct function - rather than a `prototype method` - to be able to use within libraries and api's, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is certainly more than one way to cook an egg, and both solutions seem equally "valid", although they don't quite do the same thing or even result in the same output.

The angular solution opts to only attempt the lowercasing if the input data is a string. I can see two reasons for this. The first is potentially not wanting to waste time on passing it to the lowercase function if it's not a string. The second is that a side effect of lowercasing is that the output, regardless of input, comes back as a string, and perhaps they didn't want that.

Take the following code for example, assuming either of the above two functions:

```
var example = 1;
if (lowercase(example) + 1 === "11") {...}
```

Through the current angular way, this would return false (1 + 1 = 2).
Through the other way, this would return true ("1" + 1 = "11").

As to whether or not this is an intended side effect, I do not know. It is inconsistent with what one might expect from native javascript however, which should definitely be considered when evaluating whether or not the approach is more advantageous.

**Example**

```js
function isString(value) {
  return typeof value === 'string';
}
var lowercase1 = function(string) {
  return isString(string) ? string.toLowerCase() : string;
};


var lowercase2 = Function.prototype.call.bind(''.toLowerCase);

var tests = ["ExAmPlE", "12345", 67890, "true", true, [1, 2, 3], {win: 1, lose: 0}];
var strings = ['"ExAmPlE"', '"12345"', '67890', '"true"', 'true', '[1, 2, 3]', '{bar: 1}'];

for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
  var low1 = lowercase1(tests[i]);
  var low2 = lowercase2(tests[i]);
  $('#test').append('<th>' + strings[i] + '</th>');
  $('#ang').append('<td>' + typeof low1 + '</td>');
  $('#nat').append('<td>' + typeof low2 + '</td>');
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th, td {
  min-width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="test">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="ang">
    <th>Angular</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="nat">
    <th>Native</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I did some testing earlier and I didn't notice any difference in output. I thought their was that 'type' check that was the difference. But when I checked there was no error thrown on either. So... I get back to you on your aswer when I have more time to look thx for answer in mean time

Comment: @jamie I've added a runnable example to my post. It gives a comparison of the different "typeof" outputs produced by each function after a variety of input types. The "isString" function is taken from angular.

Comment: wow super - I didn't get that far. So the angular way keeps the `type` in check. And native somehow converts anything to `string-like type`. Went to the MDN site to see the src code. They don't publish it or the normal polyfill info at the end. You don't know where to find it? Hat's off on that answer:)

Comment: @jamie Here's the most recent changelog I could find: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/56861f2edc5d/js/src/jit-test/tests/latin1/toLowerCase-toUpperCase.js

Which I found here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1019543 EDIT: Found the javascript one, added as first link above ;)

Comment: JS one was a test, my mistake. Here's the old first CPP file link. Just search for ToLowerCase: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/56861f2edc5d/js/src/jsstr.cpp

Comment: wow- super all around. Thanks - clarified a lot of things and helped in some workflow stuff. cheers